# How to interpret and report significant glmmADMB interaction term?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons

I am analyzing a data set using `glmmADMB` and determining significance of variables using likelihood ratio tests to compare models with and without a given variable. Using this method, I have found a significant interaction between two factors, but I’m not quite sure how to move forward and perform multiple comparisons of the interaction term.

The interaction is between treatment (`treat.a`) and distance from the treatment (`dist.a`). There are 3 treatments (`A`, `P`, and `W`) and a control. I used `relevel` to set control as the reference level. There are two distances (`near` and `far`).

Below is my actual summary output.

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = blk.a ~ year + apt.a + dist.a + treat.a + 
    dist.a:treat.a + (1 | date.a/plot.a) + (1 | plot.a), family = "nbinom2")

AIC: 12653.8 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -4.65e+00   1.18e+00   -3.95  7.8e-05 ***
year2013             1.26e+00   1.58e+00    0.80  0.42584    
year2014            -1.37e+00   1.75e+00   -0.78  0.43441    
apt.a                7.59e-04   5.28e-05   14.38  < 2e-16 ***
dist.anear          -1.08e-02   1.14e-01   -0.09  0.92454    
treat.aA             2.45e-01   3.58e-01    0.68  0.49496    
treat.aP             8.54e-02   3.59e-01    0.24  0.81177    
treat.aW             5.65e-01   3.56e-01    1.59  0.11271    
dist.anear:treat.aA  5.70e-01   1.54e-01    3.70  0.00021 ***
dist.anear:treat.aP  5.49e-01   1.56e-01    3.52  0.00044 ***
dist.anear:treat.aW  3.42e-01   1.52e-01    2.26  0.02400 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=11548, date.a=39, date.a:plot.a=624, plot.a=16 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=date.a
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)     15.3  3.912
Group=date.a:plot.a
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)    1.052  1.026
Group=plot.a
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)   0.1727 0.4156

Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 0.82999 (std. err.: 0.039214)

Log-likelihood: -6311.9 
Warning message:
In .local(x, sigma, ...) :
  'sigma' and 'rdig' arguments are present for compatibility only: ignored
```

The only interaction I’m interested in besides what is shown in the summary is the comparison between ControlNear and ControlFar. How do I make that comparison?

Is it appropriate for me to apply a correction for multiple comparisons to these P-values and report them as such?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. Also, if you notice anything funky in my output that raises a red flag, please let me know. I'm very new to mixed effects models.